# No "fdisk" command in Debian wheezy

Tags: partitioning, debian, fdisk

I need to see how my disk is partitioned and I remeber that I have to use the command

> fdisk -l

but in Debian wheezy is not installed. I installed

> gnu-fdisk

but nothing change.

How can I resolve? Are there other programs could help me in the same way?

Comment: Ok I installed fdisk with live cd. Probably there were some issue on my installation version. But are there other programs to see how the disk is partitioned?

Comment: if you're using a livecd, probably gparted/qtparted/parted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you doing this as a regular user or as root? Try it as root if you're doing it as a regular user. Else, use the command `which fdisk` and use the path it gives

Comment: Yes. now it works. Do you know other programs or command to do the same thing?

Comment: offhand, anything thats in your root user's path but not in that user's path. anything thats in the directories listed when you run `echo $PATH` should run without the full path. Else, you would need the full path *and* appropriate permissions to run it. Also, just curious, if it works, what else would this answer need to be the right one? Just wondering if i missed something

Comment: you're right... :)

Comment: This is one difference between Debian/Ubuntu. Out of the box I believe Ubuntu adds /usr/bin path to all users. On Debian it only adds that path for the root user.

Comment: I have debian wheezy ppc. No fdisk available but /sbin/mac-fdisk".